# File both exists and not exists in Go?

Tags: file, go

Is there some reason why this Go program says neither that a file exists nor doesn't exist? Presumably it's one or the other?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    for _, fn := range os.Args[1:] {
        src, _ := filepath.Abs(fn)
        fmt.Println(fn)
        fmt.Println(src)
        if _, e := os.Stat(src); os.IsExist(e) {
            log.Fatalf("Does exist: %s", src)
        }
        if _, e := os.Stat(src); os.IsNotExist(e) {
            log.Fatalf("Does not exist: %s", src)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The os.IsExist and os.IsNotExist functions do not test opposite conditions, even though the names seem to imply that they do.

The function [os.IsExist](http://godoc.org/os#IsExist) returns true when an operation fails because a file already exists. The function [os.IsNotExist](http://godoc.org/os#IsNotExist) returns true when the operation fails because the file does not exist.

The function os.Stat always returns an error with os.IsExist(err) == false. The os.Stat function never fails because the file exists.

The function os.OpenFile with O_CREAT always returns an error os.IsNotExist(err) == false. Because the purpose of os.OpenFile with O_CREAT is to create a file, it is never an error for the file to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

Some functions fail if a file exists. The error returned by such a system call would satisfy `os.IsExist()`. One such system call is `os.OpenFile()` with flags `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`. Other functions fail if a file does not exist, like `os.OpenFile` without the `O_CREAT` flag. The error returned by such a system call would satisfy `os.IsNotExist()`. The `nil` error satisfies neither `os.IsExist()` and `os.IsNotExist()` as it is not a failure condition.

In your example, the `os.Stat()` function could fail if the file you try to stat does not exist. It could also fail if the file existed, but not for the reason of the file existing. Therefore, `os.IsExist(e)` will always yield `false` for an error produced by the `os.Stat()` function.

Comment: So, you're saying that `os.IsExist()` can return false for a file that exists?

Comment: @Ana Yes. `os.IsExist()` classifies an *error*. If the cause of an error `e` was the existance of a file, `os.IsExist(e)` is true. The `nil` error is not a proper error, as it indicates success and thus has no cause.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to check if file exists (where src = path to file):

```
if _, err := os.Stat(src); err == nil || os.IsExist(err) {
    // your code here if file exists
}
```